# log4j gradle configuration - Unable to locate implementation error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, log4j, slick2d

i'm trying to get log4j 2.8 working with a slick2d / lwjgl project using gradle/intellij.

Sadly I am unable to resolve this log4j error:
"ERROR StatusLogger Unable to locate a logging implementation, using SimpleLogger"

There is a section about this error in the log4j [FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#missing_core) but I dont think I am missing these jars since I include them using the gradle dependencies specified [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/maven-artifacts.html):

```
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.8'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.8'
```

Adding "-Dlog4j.debug" to the VM options to get some more information on the error seems to do nothing.

I also placed a "log4j.xml" configuration file in src/main/resources but it doesn't look like log4j is finding it.

Does someone know what could be causing all this?

Comment: See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html. The file should be named `log4j2.xml` to be found automatically. To understand why core dependency is not found please share a reproducible test case project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to always refresh the gradle project...i had the same problem for 3 days and i didn't figured it out. Randomly i saw a question on that and it worked.

if you did that, look in the mavenrepository. there is no log4j version 2.8 [Here is the link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api).

So i think the solution is:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.7'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.7'
```

and i hope it works!

Comment: sadly changing the version and refreshing did not help, but thx

Comment: have you checked your .jar files? is there the corresponding log4j jar for core and api inside?